# Deserializing xml into object returns null

Tags: c#, xml, object

It counts correctly the number of objects but returns null or zero.I have lots of a lot of classes to fill with xml content.I need an efficient method to import xml to my C# app. Is my xml file corrupt?

**Xml file:**

```
<Entitati>
  <Entitate>
    <nume>asd</nume>
    <actiuni>25</actiuni>
    <valoare>2.05</valoare>
  </Entitate>
  <Entitate>
    <nume>fgh</nume>
    <actiuni>50</actiuni>
    <valoare>3.14</valoare>
  </Entitate>
  <Entitate>
    <nume>fanel</nume>
    <actiuni>35</actiuni>
    <valoare>5.15</valoare>
  </Entitate>
</Entitati>
```

**Classes:**

```
[XmlRoot("Entitati")]
public class Entitati
{
    [XmlElement("Entitate")]
    public List<Entitate> entitati { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Entitate")]
public class Entitate
{
     [XmlElement("nume")]
     protected string nume { get; set; }
     [XmlElement("actiuni")]
     protected int actiuniDisponibile { get; set; }
     [XmlElement("valoare")]
     protected double valoareActiune { get; set; }
}
```

**Main:**

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Entitati));
using (FileStream fileStream = new 
FileStream("C:\\Users\\batrinut\\Desktop\\Entitati.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
      Entitati result = (Entitati)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: `Entitati result` only exists in the `using` block. You know that, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties in the `Entitate` class should not be `protected`.

Changing then to `public` should do the trick.

```
namespace SOTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Entitati));
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                Entitati result = (Entitati)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Entitati")]
    public class Entitati
    {
        [XmlElement("Entitate")]
        public List<Entitate> entitati { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Entitate")]
    public class Entitate
    {
        [XmlElement("nume")]
        public string nume { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("actiuni")]
        public int actiuniDisponibile { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("valoare")]
        public double valoareActiune { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste here the code as text, not as picture.